# Series convergent mathematics question

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this question on convergent series. I know how to answer the question but am stuck on the cancelling down of terms. I have attached a picture of the answer to my question and have underlined in red the part I am stuck on. On the part I have underlined I do not understand where the n^2 on the numerator and n^3 on the denominator have come from.

Kind regards,
Tessa

[image]

Comment: We have $n+2=n(1+2/n)$ which squared yields $n^2(1+2/n)^2$ due to the rule $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$ which is readily checked since $(ab)^2=abab=aabb=a^2b^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_n = \frac{(n+1)^2}{n!}$, then
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\frac{(n+2)^2}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{(n+1)^2}{n!}} = \frac{n!(n+2)^2}{(n+1)!(n+1)^2} = \frac{(n+2)^2}{(n+1)(n+1)^2}=\frac{(n+2)^2}{(n+1)^3} = \frac{[n(1+\frac2n)]^2}{[n(1+\frac1n)]^3} = \frac{n^2}{n^3}\frac{(1+\frac2n)^2}{(1+\frac1n)^3} = \frac{1}{n}\frac{(1+\frac2n)^2}{(1+\frac1n)^3}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Since 
$$n+2=n\left(1+\frac 2n\right)$$
$$n+1=n\left(1+\frac 1n\right)$$
one has
$$\frac{(n+2)^2}{(n+1)^3}=\frac{\left(n \left(1+\frac 2n\right)\right)^2}{\left(n\left(1+\frac 1n\right)\right)^3}=\frac{n^2\left(1+\frac 2n\right)^2}{n^3\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^3}$$